# GLFW installation Win64 bit Mingw eclipse

Tags: c, glfw

Please who can guide me correctly to install glfw on windows for use with Mingw64 in eclipse IDE.

I have downloaded the glfw binaries for Mingw64 and created directory at C:/Program Files(x86). Extracted the GLFW files to that directory and even copied glfw3.h to my MingW include folder, copied libglfw.a and glfw3.dll to the lib folder. But when I type

`enter code here`#include <GL/glfw3.h>

in C, it displays "unresolved inclusion.

Please help

Comment: Also you may want to switch to msys2 and have package management with mingw where you can install packages like this with a tool called pacman. https://www.msys2.org/

Comment: Please there is no folder named GL in the glfw-3.3.4 version, please guide

Comment: I am sorry `#include <GL/glfw3.h>` is the bug. It should be `#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>` as in the official documentation here: [https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/build.html](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/build.html) and the files you should have installed are listed at the end of this page: [https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-glfw](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-glfw) the .cmake files are optional and only needed if you use a program called CMake